# rspec - how can I check if a method exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model has

```
def self.empty_building
  // stuff
end
```

How can I rspec for this existing?, have tried:

```
describe "empty_building" do
  subject { Building.new }
  it { should respond_to :empty_building }
end

but getting :

Failure/Error: it { should respond_to :empty_building }  
expected #<Building id: nil, district_id: nil, name: nil, 
direct: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to :empty_building
```

Comment: Not to be a dick, but imo, these kinds of tests aren't worth writing. Every time you call the method in, you will implicitly assert this. The only real reason I can think of to do this kind of thing is to ensure interface integrity, and there are generally better tools for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a class method

```
self.empty_building
```

in your model.. but your subject is an instance of Building.

So either, it should be

```
def empty_building
```

or it should be:

```
describe "empty_building" do
  it { Building.should respond_to :empty_building }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, yet this answer still gives an error - `     Failure/Error: it { Building.should respond_to :empty_building }                                                                                                                                                      {│       expected building(id: integer, district_id: integer, name: string, direct: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated                                                                                                A│_at: datetime) to respond to :empty_building   `

Comment: btw I want it to be a class level method.

Comment: This gave me a false positive. `empty_building` could be anything in `{ Building.should respond_to :empty_building }` and it would pass.